# OpenFileDialog is minimising parent form

Tags: c#, winforms, openfiledialog

I'm using `OpenFileDialog` within a `WinForms`application and I can't work out how to get the parent form to show after calling `OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog()`.

The functionality is working fully as expected. The problem is that the form stays minimised to the system tray after the `OpenFileDialog` has been called, and I can't get it to show in its original position without manually opening the window from the tray.

**Constructor**

```
 public Simulator()
 {
     InitializeComponent();
     LoadMachine();
     ...
 }
```

**Enclosing method**

```
private void LoadMachine()
{
    ...        
    //LoadFile is the OpenFileDialog
    LoadFile.InitialDirectory = Application.StartupPath;
    if (LoadFile.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK) return;
    else
    {
        //some file IO stuff here
    }
}
```

I have tried using `this.Focus()`,`this.BringToFront()`, `FormWindowState.Maximise` and `FormWindowState.Normal` amongst others but nothing seems to restore the window. Google and SO have yielded no solutions for me. Any ideas?

Comment: you have LoadFile but don't show us any detail about it.   I assume you subclassed the OpenFileDialog.

Comment: I included that in my edit. `LoadFile` is the name of the `OpenFileDialog` that is part of my form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try putting `LoadMachine()` in a `Shown` event for `Simulator`. The `ShowDialog` code is being run before the Form is shown.

Example:

```
    private void Simulator_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LoadMachine();
    }
```